# Mysql not using an index when selecting a non-indexed field

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table `meta` with the following structure (this is just an example denormalized data)

```
`id` int(3) not null auto_increment primary key,
`category_id` int(3),
`subdomain` varchar(191),
`created_at` timestamp,
`updated_at` timestamp
```

The `subdomain` field could store unique values and repeating values like 'general' can be repeated many times

**Situation 1**

Also i have an index `subdomain`. This index applied on query

```
Select `id` from `table` where `subdomain` = 'general'
```

But when i try to get some non-indexed field, mysql scans all table and index is not used

```
Select `created_at` from `table` where `subdomain` = 'general'
```

As i know, Inno-db non-clustered index stores a reference to a row and there is no need to perform linear search over all rows to retrieve some field.

Also i know optimizer can choose an unexpected plan for human, but what the reasons can be in this case?

No matter how much data in the table, result always the same.

Comment: "but what the reasons can be in this case" - **Cardinality**. The optimizer has estimated, that it makes no sense to use an index for search and then to make a second lookup in the clustered index, because there are too many rows with `subdomain = 'general'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen, when the filtering backed by the index is *not very selective*/your value to filter for has a *high cardinality*. This means a high percentage of your total rows match the where-condition supported by the index (e.g. 90% of your rows match `subdomain = 'general'`). If you use the index under that condition you end up processing more data compared to a full table scan.

Example: you have 100 rows and 90 of them match `subdomain = 'general'`.

A full table scan needs to access all 100 rows to check the conditaion and 90 values are read for the result.

An index backed select needs to access 90 items in the index fo fulfill the condition and follow the pointer from the index to the actual row to select the not indexed value from that row. Ending up in 90 lookups on the index + 90 reads from the rows = 180 operations. This is slower than the full table scan where you just access some rows more than needed. The operations might not have the same cost, but you end up doing more work in the end.